# Delete file created with php script from php

Tags: php, file-handling

I have a script that creates, updates or delete a file given the argument on my /var/www/ folder.

```
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'PUT' ){
            $params = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
            $myfile = fopen( '/var/www/folder/'. $params->name , "w") or die('failed to open file'. $params['name']);
            fwrite( $myfile, $params->command );
            fclose();
    } else if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'DELETE' ){
            $params = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
            echo unlink( '/var/www/folder/'. $params->name )? "The file was deleted" : "The file was not deleted". '\n';
    }
```

I am having an issue, though. The files that are being succesfully created in the folder, aren't being deleted by the unlink command - that returns false.

The apache server is running on a Ubuntu machine. *'folder'* permissions are 777 and also are the permissions for this script.

Files created inside the folder are of the user:group www-data. Its permissions are the default permissions.

Any ideas on why I the script can't delete the files it has created itself?

Comment: Try to trigger an E_WARNING by execute 'unlink( '/var/www/folder/'. $params->name )'. What error message do you get?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your php error log or in your server error log when you attempt the unlink?

Comment: @BobDill just cheked, yes I am. Thank you. Now I know that the problem is that *file_get_contents("php://input")* is comming out empty. Still digging out why.

Comment: what do you find if you echo the contents returned from your file_get_contents request without the json_decode? Is it possible that you're not passing the file name back to your php script from your web side?

Comment: Found out the issue. The android http library (Volley) ignores the content for DELETE requests. Thank you for your help!